# Update Multiple PivotTables in Excel DataModel

Tags: excel, pivot-table, datamodel

I have a few pivot table and pivot charts in a few different sheets. However, my pivot table and charts are come from datamodel. Is there a way to perform a vba whereby the datamodel will update the range from the datasource and later update all the pivot table and charts.

Comment: You mean you have a reason to avoid using `Workbook.RefreshAll`?

Comment: @JosWoolley Workbook.RefreshAll is not applicable. I need to update row from my datasource first so that the datamodel is updated. directly RefreshAll won't update this thing

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*the datamodel will update the range from the datasource*"?

Comment: @JosWoolley i have a sheets where every month there' a new data will be added. and my datamodel was coming from this data sheets. so what i mean is that, my datamodel need to be update the range first based on this data sheets then all the picot table will be refresh accordingly

Comment: But data added to the datamodel must come from tables, and if those tables expand than a refresh of the datamodel will take account of that expansion. I don't understand what you mean when you say that the datamodel comes from a "sheet", since the datamodel comprises tables, not sheets.

Comment: @JosWoolley i also don't understand you. because my datamodel come from one tables whereby that tables was from the data sheet. the table is not from the air